# Mathematica doesn't know Cos[2] or even Sin[12 Degree]!

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried with some common angles like pi/2, pi/3 or pi/6 but and it works but when you use uncommon angles like 2 rad or 12 degree mathematica doesn't return any value! Please don't tell me mathematica uses a 20 entry table or something like that for cosine and sine!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the sin/cos of those angles have no exact representation (like, say `Cos[45 Degree]` which is *1/sqrt(2)*), you'll need to do `N[Cos[2]]` and `N[Sin[12 Degree]]` (i.e. `N[...]`).

> In[1]:=  Cos[2]
>   Out[1]:= Cos[2]
>
> In[2]:=  N[Cos[2]]
>   Out[2]:= -0.416147

Comment: You may also write `Cos[2] // N`.

Comment: `Cos[2.]` gives the same output. Note the dot after the number.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica tries to preserve the precision of a calculation. Integers are considered infinity precise, so to get an approximate decimal answer you must have at least one approximate number in the input or use the N function.

```
Sin[2.0]
Sin[2.0`50]
N[Sin[2],50]
```

For investigating rational multiples of pi there are several options.
(In version 9.0)

Some are expanded automatically, for example:

```
Sin[Pi/12]
```

Try **FunctionExpand**, **RootReduce**, and **ToRadicals**.

```
Sin[12 Degree] // FunctionExpand
```

gives:

```
-(1/8) Sqrt[3] (-1 + Sqrt[5]) + 1/4 Sqrt[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]
```

Using Degree seems to indicate to Mathematica that the user is probably at a lower math level and doesn't want to see complex numbers or algebraic number objects so instead of

```
Sin[x Degree]
```

use

```
Sin[x Pi/180]
```

sin of 1 degree:

```
Sin[Pi/180] // RootReduce
% // ToRadicals
```

Sometimes results may be disappointing:

```
Sin[Pi/77]
```

can't be expressed in a more informative form than:

```
-(1/2) (-1)^(75/154) (-1 + (-1)^(2/77))
```

or

```
1/2 Sqrt[root of some huge polynomial]
```

This is due to limitations of mathematical language, not Mathematica. See Galois theory. Examples of what Mathematica can write without complex numbers or Root objects:

```
Table[{(\[Pi] k)/180, If[FreeQ[#, (-1)^x_], #, Style[Sin[(\[Pi] k)/180], Red]] &@
ToRadicals[Sin[(\[Pi] k)/180]]}, {k, 45}] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters or people just interested, what is going, Mathematica offers some forensic function as well. That does not bring You any closer to the desired result though.

For example FullForm from Mathematica Help.

FullForm[expr]
prints as the full form of expr, with no special syntax.

```html
FullForm[Cos[2]]
```

Give the same result that disappointed You so much. But the help page for the function might bring You a lot further and can be an inspiration for further steps on own feed. It goes further into the concept "Everything is an expression". That is too a paradigm of Mathematica and at the very foundations of Mathematica. A part of this paradigma is already mention,

```
Cos[2]
```

will not be evaluated. It is something on its own. This paradigma should not be and is in no way intended to cause disappointment or keep people of from using Mathematica.

Mathematica can too show mixed numeric and symbolic representation:

```html
N[10, 4] Sin[.25 x]
```

The N function is in need to be taken under You closer examination. One of the explanation is:

```html
The precision n is given in decimal digits; it need not be an integer.
```

This is rather confusing because integer and decimal digits have the very same representation in Mathematica.

```html
N[Cos[2]]
```

=-0.416147

Is the action for You from the Mathematica kernel with default percision.

Since the market introduction of Wolfram Alpha Mathematica is much smarter than that. It offers = as a new kind of input. The equal sign without everything else is turned into an orange underlayed equal sign in white. That means You are admitted to enter real world mathematical expressions for example from school books to get a meaningful traditional kind of mathematical answer.

All You have to do in Mathematica 12 is to click an the all answer symbol and more than enough simple answers as known from Wolfram Alpha will be given to You.

Have another try or attempt on Mathematica. It is real fun.